# Django python manage.py makemigrations causes a problem with databases

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am starting with Django and I got this problem. I understand only that there is a problem with database. I would really like to get some help. Thank you, If it is important I use Fedora 33

Guys really, not my bad that the 90% of problem is code, let me as a question XD

```
(project_venv) [mikolajwojtowicz@localhost src]$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 411, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/Django/my_project/src/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/Django/my_project/src/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 290, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    tables = self.connection.introspection.table_names(cursor)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 48, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 43, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/introspection.py", line 74, in get_table_list
    cursor.execute("""
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value 
 File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/mikolajwojtowicz/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 411, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: file is not a database
```

Comment: Your database file settings are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The error log says:

```
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database
```

This means that your settings for the database are wrong. This setting is located in the `settings.py` in your core project's directory (this directory will also have wsgi.py and asgi.py)

Make sure your settings for db engine, name, user, and password are correct